# How to call click event on Android ListView Header?

Tags: android, listview

I created a list view and I added a header  to it (by using addHeaderview(layout)), then I wrote a click event like:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buypwr, null);
itemView.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
}
```

But this onClick event didn't fire when I clicked on the header, so can anyone tell me how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just try this..

```
itemView.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListner()
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
   }
}
```

If you have TextView in buypwr.xml then try this

```
TextView txt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(......);
txt.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListner()
    {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
       }
    }
```

Comment: Nopes still not firing the event. :(

Comment: which view in your buypwr.xml ?

Comment: if you have any TextView or Button or ImageView in header then you need to find that view and apply onClick on it..

Comment: please check my buypwr xml from here http://pastebin.com/sQ6HNnrH and i'm adding this layout to listview header as explained above

Comment: then you want onclick on particular on textview or all portion?

Comment: Yup! thanks a lot its working now, and i applied Collections.sort(list) but it doesn't sorted the array of strings could plz help me what is the prob?

Comment: Arrays.sort(list); where list = String[].. means array of string

Comment: means you want sort all item when user click on textview?

Comment: yes u'r right. But see when i gave arrya.sort(list) at the start of activity its working but when i put in click event its not working.

Comment: then you must need to refresh your listview. after click on textview

Comment: i tried like this list.invalidateViews(); its working but how can i get back original view when i click again on it?

Comment: then you need to setAdapter again without call Arrays.sort(COUNTRIES);

Comment: but i've only one event right, so how can i call again setAdapter and Arrays.sort(list) in same event i think i need to give some condition?

Answer (score 4):

If you want clickable Header as basic list item. Inflate it with ListView.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
mListView.addHeaderView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_header, mListView, false));
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
            //Prepare to get it at position == 0
        }
    });
```

Comment: headerview is only selectable for once ...using you suggestion,could you explain me why ?

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

When inflating the header view, before adding it to the listview, I then used that view to get the subview and add a click listener on it

```
myHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... } );
```

also, when I added it to the listView, I used the overloaded constructor with the third variable set to `true`

```
mListView.addHeaderView(myHeaderView, null, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use setOnItemClickListener to set the click event for the list and implement a customized OnItemClickListener for your own use.

android.widget.AdapterView.setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener)

Comment: No i'm implementing click event for view, which is used as a header in my listview and this view doesn't having any Onitemclicklistner.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any specific widgets (buttons etc) which can have listener, you can get your header by calling onItemClickListener() as @Nicoloas said at position 0 as its the first item. You can even set a specific id for you header view and access it in onItemClickListener() by calling view.getId(). Let me know if otherwise.